# How to commit when inserting records by calling Postgres function

Tags: python, postgresql, plsql, sqlalchemy

I wrote a function to insert record to table `person`. Row ID is serial (auto-increment)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.add_person(
    name character varying,
    email character varying,
    level integer,
    company_id integer,
    comp_list integer[])
    RETURNS integer as

$BODY$
declare 
    p_id integer;
begin 
    insert into person (name, email, level, company_id, comp_list, status, insert_ts) values ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, 'Y', now())
    returning person.person_id into p_id;
    return p_id;
end
$BODY$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

If I run this function with sql `select * from add_person('xxx', 'xxx@gmail.com', 1, 3, '{1,2}')`, it inserts a record successfully. However when I call this function in Python using SQLAlchemy, record can't get inserted.

```
engine = create_engine(URL(**settings.DATABASE))
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
email = 'xxx@gmail.com'
company = 1
level = 3
comp_list = '1,2'
args = "'', '" + email + "', " + str(company) + ", " + str(level) + ", '{" + comp_list + "}'"
statement = "select * from add_person({})".format(args)
session.execute(statement)
```

The statement constructed in Python is exactly the same as the command I run in postgres. But it did not insert record into the table like it is supposed to. No error message at all. The `session`, `engine` are configured correctly because all other `select` queries work.

I also noticed that even though the records can't be inserted using python code. The sequence of primary key did increase. Because when I run the function again in postgres, the row ID skipped.

The behavior is the same if I do the insert with SQLAlchemy session without commit.

```
def add_person(name, email, company, level, comp_list):
    current_ts = datetime.datetime.now()
    p = Person(name = name,
               email = email,
               company_id = company,
               level = level,
               comp_list = comp_list,
               status = 'Y',
               insert_ts = current_ts)
    session.add(p)
    session.flush()
    return p.person_id
```

If I run the Python method above, `person_id` increments but no record is inserted. Only when I change `session.flush` to the following, the record gets inserted correctly.

```
    session.add(p)
    session.commit()
    session.refresh(p)
    print(p.person_id)
    return p.person_id
```

What is the correct way to commit inserts when calling that plsql function?

Comment: Try `conn.autocommit = True` see [Transactions control.](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#transactions-control)

Comment: Please *do not use string formatting* for passing values to queries. That's what placeholders/bindparams are for. Read http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql for "how" and https://xkcd.com/327/ for "why".

Comment: You don't even need textual SQL here. Function generics would allow you to do `execute(func.add_person('', email, company, level, comp_list.split(',')).select())`. Note that you could and should pass comp_list as just that, a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have `autocommit` on the connection set to `True` you will need to call the `commit()` function of the session.

Documentation: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_basics.html#when-do-i-construct-a-session-when-do-i-commit-it-and-when-do-i-close-it

---

The reason your `person_id` incremented even without the commit is because it is using a sequence - either your created that explicitly or it was created for you when you defined the column type as `SERIAL` (or similar). That sequence will increment with or without a commit and does not depend on the successful insertion of a record in the table.

Note that calling a commit is not required for statements only involving `SELECT`.